# Black box in new composition - After Effects CC

Tags: after-effects, adobe

Hiya new to after effects and trying to follow along with a tutorial. Can't figure out though why there is a black box when I make a new composition? I've imported an illustrator file with different layers I don't think I'm zoomed in too much perhaps theres some kind of view I'm in I need to get out of?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Theres also a warning dialogue box that pops up before I open After Effects potentially that has something to do with it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that's just the composition preview window - where you'll see what you've put into the comp. If you need to change the size of the window, right-click the comp name and go to 'Composition settings'. I also like to change the background colour of my comps to something like #8E4545 to differentiate from black elements and the 'empty' screen.

The warning message is telling you that you need more space on the drive that your disk cache is stored on (sort of like preview files that are generated when you render the content in your AE project). Go to Edit > Preferences > Media & Disk Cache to clear it out or change how much storage it's allowed to access.

Comment: Thanks @Jamie Bruce I still don't understand why my layers aren't showing? The video tutorial has her layers showing before shes started doing anything